# how to bind a command when fish shell is started

Tags: fish

Instead of using !! in bash, I am using a function to prepend sudo after a key combination.It seems the only way to use it is to bind the key every time a new shell is created. I have tried putting

> bind \cs 'prepend_command sudo'

in ~/.config/fish/config.fish but to no avail. How can I bind the key at the start of every fish shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put your bindings in `fish_user_key_bindings`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660301/fish-programming-why-are-bind-commands-in-config-fish-not-executed) for some more detailed instructions.